# Adding a class to a tag

Tags: jquery

I want to add a class to my

```
<p class="formField" id="equipmentTypeContent">some content is here...</p>
```

Here is how I tried to do that but it's not working:

```
$('#equipmentTypeContent').addClass("singleEquipmentText");
```

I don't know if in this case jQuery needs to know what type of element it is (in this case a

tag) in addition to the type of tag?  I doubt it, I think it only needs the id of the element you're manipulating right?

Comment: Make sure that you have loaded jQuery on your page properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. See the [working copy](http://jsfiddle.net/yBuFn/) on jsFiddle

Comment: tried to run that code you pasted into jsFiddler.  I removed the class from the <p> tag then clicked run...I don't see the class being added when I run this.  Maybe I'm using jsFiddler wrong or something.

Comment: in my example, singleEquipmentText class is setting  1px black border,  and in the results pane, you should see two pixel height black line. That means class was added at runtime. And note, that jQuery code is run on dom ready handler, as specified on the left side of jsfiddle window

Comment: yea but I should be able to see a view source and see that class added to my <p> and I dno't when I run my code.

Comment: I've been running jquery code fine on this page without the ready.  You only need the ready if you are first loading the dom on loading page.  If the page is already loaded and the user is just interacting with html controls, the DOM has DEFINITELY been loaded by that time.

Comment: Yes, that is true if the dom is already loaded, you do not need ready event. What are you checking class existance with? View source does not show you that. Use chrome inspector, or firebug on firefox to see realtime page contents. That way, class should be visible

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems fine but you need to wrap your code in [ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(function(){
  $('#equipmentTypeContent').addClass("singleEquipmentText");
});
```

Also make sure that you have loaded jQuery on your page.

Comment: why now?  I haven't had to wrap other manipulations in my code for this page

Comment: I've been working with ids of some elements fine already... such as using jquery to hide show dropdowns in this page and so on...without having to introduce the ready

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: Because jQuery needs to be able to find elements after they have *loaded* for which you use ready handler.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: In case there is some other error, try to use firebug console for that.

Comment: I know that but so far, the way I've been calling this is on an event...not having to wait on a page load.  This action happens on an event off a dropdownlist.  And by the time the user selects something from one of the dropdown lists on my page, the dom has already loaded way before this...so in this case I'm not trying to set something immediately after the page is fetched...

Comment: the problem is how am trying to add.  The syntax isn't right to add to that <p>.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: Your code posted is fine, just make sure that a class singleEquipmentText exists in your css.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/HNpGk/1/) is a fiddle showing how to do it (and proving it by returning the updated class of the p element) after a selection is changed in a dropdown.

I'm using the jQuery `.change()` function to execute certain code after the value of the select element is changed. In this case, I take the value of the select element, strip the spaces, and add the resulting, space-free string as a class to the p element.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your code try with with jquery ready function if the script is above your HTML

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#equipmentTypeContent').addClass("singleEquipmentText");
});
```

YOu can access using the class too if you want to add to all of them with that class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.formField').addClass("singleEquipmentText");
});
```